# AngularJS - Get ng-model by html element

Tags: angularjs

I am new with Angular,

Then I want to get model data using javascript.

I want if is possible to getting with javascript a model value using the $scope and html element?

Is this the way to do??

```
<div class="tax-concept-form" ng-controller="TaxesController as taxes" ng-init="taxes.init()">
    <table cellspacing="0" class="taxes-table table ctrl-3" id="tabla_edicion" tabindex="">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="_tax in taxes.list" class="javorai-master-detail-row item-selectable" ng-model="_tax" id="row_{{_tax.id}}">
                <td>{{_tax.tax.description}}</td>
                <td>{{_tax.tax.rate}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
   </table>
<script>
//I have a angular $scope
//some javascript

var el = document.getElementById('row_1');

//I want the tax of row_1
</script>
```

Comment: ng-model is useless on a `tr`. ng-model is used on form elements (inputs, textarea, select), in order to populate the model with what the user enters/selects. A user doesn't enter anything in a `tr`. Why would you use the dom to find the nth element of an array that is in your model? Just use `$scope.taxes.list[1]` in your controller.

Comment: great.. How to I could to do a Binding Data with a TR?? sorry If my question is very Bad.

Comment: You're already doing it. Just drop the ng-model which is useless: each tr has two tds, and each td shows a n attribute of the current tax object. What's the problem? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a keyboard listener (for all.. this works well).. But I am adding Angular and I want to use the same keyboard listener.. and when the user press a key (example: Enter, Escape, Key Up, Key Down) I want to change the model data of a row. The keyboard lister pass me the html element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not recommended to work with DOM elements in your controllers:

```
> Do not use controllers to:

Manipulate DOM — Controllers should contain only business logic. Putting any presentation logic into Controllers significantly affects its testability. Angular has databinding for most cases and directives to encapsulate manual DOM manipulation.
Format input — Use angular form controls instead.
Filter output — Use angular filters instead.
Share code or state across controllers — Use angular services instead.
Manage the life-cycle of other components (for example, to create service instances).
```

Instead you use data binding to separate view and business logic. See [developer guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) for more details.